# Difference between 'real' and 'really' when being adverb

Tags: word-difference

As dictionaries indicated, both *real* and *really* can be the adverb. For example:

> He is finding prison life 'real tough'.

Can we instead say 'really tough' in this case?

Question: what's the difference between *real* and *really*, when they serve as an adverb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **real** is just a slang term for **really**. A long time ago, a bunch of teenagers decided that **really** would sound cooler if you left out the *ly*. And over time, **real** has become an expression on its own. So, I don't think they're completely interchangeable. In certain situations, you can replace **real** with **really** without significantly affecting the meaning of your sentences. In other situations, where **real** is part of a slang expression, it's a completely separate word with its own nuances in meaning.

Example #1:

> Hey, dude, wanna go out tonight and get boozed?
>   **For real**. Let's do it. (**for real** here is an expression)

Example #2:

> I'll hurt you **real** bad if you don't show me where you hid the money! (can be replaced with **really**, but the sentence would not sound as casual as it probably should)

Comment: How about "*I will do that in real quick*"? Can we say "*...in really quick*" instead?

Comment: @dan you'd have to say "I will do that really quickly." "Really" is modifying "quickly" which is modifying "do." It's adverb-adverb-verb. The "in" doesn't belong. That said, a lot of people would say, "I'll do that real quick." It's not necessarily correct, but it's common.

Comment: @joiedevivre, but I've seen '*real quick*' has been used in lots of contexts. For example, *i am going to go to the store real quick.* and *Pop in real quick for some fast food memes*

Comment: @dan Yes, a lot of people would say that. But it's also okay to say "really quickly" in those places instead. You can't really learn any "rules" for this, because it breaks the rules. I gave you the version that follows the rules. :)

Comment: I wouldn't call "real tough" *slang*, I'd call it "colloquial" or "informal".