# Real good time or really good time

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Which one of the following two sentences is correct?

> They have had a **real** good time.
>
> They have had a **really** good time.

I think both of them are correct because **real** can also be used as adjective to emphasize something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between 'real' and 'really' when being adverb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/149498/difference-between-real-and-really-when-being-adverb) In colloquial (especially, *American*) English ***real*** can be used as a "flat adverb" (as in *Come **quick!**, Don't drive **fast**, I like to dance **slow***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is "real" an _adverb_ in this sentence? What verb does it modify? It appears to me to be used as an adjective modifying "time" and therefore I'd argue this sentence, while quite common, is not strictly grammatical.

Comment: @TypeIA: I happen to know the term "flat adverb", which specifically applies to the way ***real, quick, different,...*** may be used adverbially (instead of ***really, quickly differently,...***). In which context, ***fast*** is a "true" flat adverb (there is no ***-ly*** adverbial form ***fastly***). But I'm not really *(**real?!**)* interested in "the naming of the parts" - simply pointing out that even though pedants may think some of these "flat" usages are syntactically questionable, many real live native speakers use them all the time.

Comment: @TypeIA "Adverb" is a catch-all category for words that don't fit other categories. Some adverbs modify verbs, some adverbs modify adjectives, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are grammatically correct sentences.

Using the former to mean the latter is common in American English, but not so common in British English.

Comment: I agree with the above as long as "real" is not used in an examination.